# WCF method messed up

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a wcf method as follow,

```
GetData(string a, string b, string oldParameter)
```

I deployed it to production and now it's being used by some K2 processes (I can't change there references at all and it doesn't allows me to either)

I made this change on development to this method because of requirement changes,

```
GetData(string a, string b, string newParameter, bool? d)
```

I also deployed above WCF update to live and some clients created some processes instances for this method too.

I just realized when one of processes with old method dll referenced called WCF and I am getting null for `string newParameter` and `bool? d` which is because they don't know about change.

Now if I change WCF to older method I will break current processes and if I leave it as it is then older process instances are broken.

**How can I accommodate these both methods into one that both older and newer process instance work without error ?**

I tried adding both methods but then it's not allowed in wcf...

***Please note there is no way I could update reference to old process instance as it's not allowed***

Comment: Leave the old one as it is and create an overload with the new parameter.

Comment: >I tried adding both methods but then it's not allowed in wcf... Then give a new name to the new method and you are good to go.

Comment: @Kryptos i think you missed the point that I had different process instances calling same method, I just can't change there names or add a new method because they are third party processes and there calling code can't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very very i would say verryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy strange behaviour, I found it working like this,

```
GetData(string a, string b, string oldParameter, string newParameter, bool d)
{
    // check if oldParameter is empty/null then use newParameter
}
```

If old process calls this WCF method, I get value through `oldParameter` and if newer process instance calls it, I get `oldParameter` as null and right value in `newParameter`.

This way I am getting the value I want without breaking anything.